# UIImageView scaleAspectFill content mode is not working within a scroll view

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uiimageview, uiimage, scale

I have a `UIImageView` that I have configured like this:

```
imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
```

and later:

```
scrollView.addSubview(imageView)
```

My scrollView size and `contentSize` is the full screen.

when I set the `image` of the `imageView`, I always see the image in its original size. I have changed to another content mode to test, but it looks like it is ignored and the image is always displayed in its original size.

I suppose it is something related to being adding the image view to a scroll view, how could I solve this?

Comment: Hello, when you are calling this method or adding this line. Are you adding into viewDidLoad method ?

Comment: maybe image overflows image view's frame? try to set `imageView.clipsToBounds = true`

Comment: @NishantBhindi yes, all that things are done in `viewDidLoad`

Comment: Ok, try with either "viewDidLayoutSubviews" or "viewDidAppear" method. Call your method from any one of these methods or put your code inside any one of this methods.

Comment: @Kubba that clips the bounds but the appearance of the image is the original, it is not scaled

Comment: @NishantBhindi I tried in both methods but it is not working. Content mode of the image view keeps being ignored whatever I set...

Comment: Also, please change with below things:
`imageView.contentMode = .scaleToFill`
`imageView.clipsToBounds = true`

Comment: `clipsToBounds` shouldn't show any difference if the imageView is full screen. You'll need to show more code where you setup the image view, image and add it to the scrollView.

Comment: Can you show us the dimensions of your original image and the output of your app that displays the image incorrectly?

Comment: I am seeing the exact same problem.